# Can't get object through publish__month

Tags: python, django

I write a blog according by the book Django by Example.

```
# blog/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

url config:

```
# blog/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<str:slug>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

When I get a post in `blog/views.py`:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(
        Post,
        slug=slug,
        publish__year=year,
        publish__month=month,
        publish__day=day
        )
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

It returns 404.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/blog/2017/12/9/its-code-now
Raised by:  blog.views.post_detail
No Post matches the given query.
```

If I modify `blog/views.py`, just filter year, it returns fine:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(
            Post,
            slug=slug,
            publish__year=year,
            )
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

It seems the problem is `publish__month`. But Django support this method. 
I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: How does the url pattern for `post_detail` looks like?

Comment: Can you turn on debug, or otherwise post the Exception?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the publish date of your post matches the date you are putting into the URL?